# How to add custom column in the database and make it appear in yii2 (Advanced Template)?

Tags: php, yii2

I am new to `yii2` framework. I added a column in a table in the database and its value not appears in the `gridview` (it gives me `notset`). I don't want to regenerate the model, controller and views using `gii`. How to do that?

Comment: It shows notset because the value is null

Comment: And have you added the new column into the model validation rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to regenerate your code with gii (perhaps because of changes you have made), you can still use gii's **preview** and **diff** functions to get hints what has to be added to your code and do it manually...

Comment: Althouhg your answer is tired, but it is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to regenerate Models, Views and Controllers through Gii again. You can accomplish this by :

In your view file (probably `index.php`)

```
...
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],


        // your other attribute here
        'your_new_column_name',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
...
```

Thats it.

Comment: I already did that before ask my question. It is not working. It gives me notset.

Comment: Then in search.php (search model) have you filtered result with only few column name?

Comment: yes, I did that and it hasn't any relationship with value apperance. It just used for search action.